# Replace character in a message

Tags: java

So, basically I'm trying to replace all the characters in a message which will be input by the user. For example, if user input "dog" and input the code number "4", then the new message will be "hsk". d, **e, f, g, h**, same as o, **p, q, r, s**. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int codeNum;
    String msg;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a message");
    msg = read.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter a value for coding");
    codeNum = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("New message = " + getMsg(msg, codeNum));

    }

    public static String getMsg(String msg, int codeNum) {

    char[] Upper_Case_Array = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char[] Lower_Case_Array = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char[] digArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    char[] charArray = msg.toCharArray();


    for (int i = 0; i <= charArray.length; i++) {
        if (charArray[i] == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= Upper_Case_Array.length; j++) {
            if (charArray[i] == Upper_Case_Array[j]) {
                charArray[i] = Upper_Case_Array[j + codeNum];
            }
        }
        for (int h = 0; h <= Lower_Case_Array.length; h++) {
            if (charArray[i] == Lower_Case_Array[h]) {
                charArray[i] = Lower_Case_Array[h + codeNum];
            }
        }

        for (int u = 0; u <= digArray.length; u++) {
            if (charArray[i] == digArray[u]) {
                charArray[i] = digArray[u + codeNum];
            }
        }

    }
    return new String(charArray);
    }
}
```

It does ask the user to input message and code number, but after that I get

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26
    at Lab6.getMsg(Lab6.java:39)
    at Lab6.main(Lab6.java:22)`

How should I fix this?

Comment: Hope your homework problems are going well. The problem is that you are going up past the top end of the array. How should you adjust the index [i] so it doesn't overflow the array? (What should the computer do for "z"?)

Comment: thank you, i think i know what to do now  =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand the ASCII code for your inputs:

```
'0' - '9' = 48 - 57
'A' - 'Z' = 65 - 90
'a' - 'z' = 97 - 122
// All other characters are not affected by the code number
```

Then you'll know that after adding the code number to the ASCII value of the character you can possibly pass the maximum value of '9', 'Z', or 'z' and you would want to start back over to either '0', 'A', or 'a'.

If you know this, than you can simply your `getMsg()` and not have to worry about having arrays of uppercase, lowercase, or digits; and you don't have to do so many loops.  Something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a message: ");
    String message = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter a value for coding: ");
    int codeNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println(getMsg(message, codeNumber));
}

public static String getMsg(String message, int codeNumber) {
    char[] characters = message.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < codeNumber; j++) {
            int charCode = characters[i] + 1;
            // Only apply the modification to letters or numbers
            if (Character.isUpperCase(characters[i])) {
                characters[i] = charCode > 'Z' ? 'A' : (char)charCode;
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(characters[i])) {
                characters[i] = charCode > 'z' ? 'a' : (char)charCode;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(characters[i])) {
                characters[i] = charCode > '9' ? '0': (char)charCode;
            }
        } 
    }  
    return new String(characters);
}
```

Results:

```
Please enter a message: dog zebra 7890
Please enter a value for coding: 4
hsk difve 1234
```

Comment: Thank you!! What does "" characters[i] = charCode > 'Z' ? 'A' : (char)charCode;"" this line mean?? and how can i print the binary representation for these letters. Ex.  010001010100011001000111 wuld be EFG after coding ABC

Comment: @InvalidUserName characters[i] = charCode > 'Z' ? 'A' : (char)charCode; is a ternary operation of deciding to assigning 'A' to the element if the modified charCode has passed 'Z' otherwise the modified charCode is assigned to the element after its casted back into a character. This is what allows characters to wrap around to the beginning like my answer shows.

Comment: @InvalidUserName For binary output look at Integer.toBinaryString(), but keep in mind that ASCII characters are only seven bits in length so you'll have to pad left with zeros if you want 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds me like it is a boundary problem. So what you should do in this case is being careful about boundies of array. Well, apparently you have those lines in your code:

```
charArray[i] = Upper_Case_Array[j + codeNum];
```

and

```
charArray[i] = Lower_Case_Array[h + codeNum];
```

and

```
charArray[i] = digArray[u + codeNum];
```

Let's consider the last example. So, u being 24 will cause trouble because 24 + 4 is 28, which is greater than 26 (Since 26 letters in the English alphabet, I didn't count your array but just assumed). You may have to give explicit control for each for loop in order not to happen in this way.

But what I will suggest you, on the other way around, characters are integers so just add the integer value (codeNum) to character you have and have yours new characters by just doing that operation. I don't know if there are rules that you cannot make use of it but it gotta be worked. So specifcally, you may want to make use that line:

```
chararray[i] = charArray[i] + 4;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you!! btw i just found out that i forgot to mention, if it passes 26 then it will go back to the beginning. Ex, 24 + 4 = 28 , 26 is 'z' then goes back to 1, 2 so the ans will be 'b'. lol

Comment: In that case, use that line with respect to mod 26 ( % 26). Hope it helps you. Ofc, not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your getMsg() method if this code

```
public static String getMsg(String msg, int codeNum) {

            char[] Upper_Case_Array = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
            char[] Lower_Case_Array = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
            char[] digArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
            char[] charArray = msg.toCharArray();

            for (int i=0; i<charArray.length; i++) {
                int newIndex = 0;
                if (getIndex(Upper_Case_Array, charArray[i]) != -1) {
                    newIndex = i + codeNum;
                    if (newIndex >= Upper_Case_Array.length) {
                        newIndex = newIndex - Upper_Case_Array.length ;
                    }
                    charArray[i] = Upper_Case_Array[newIndex];
                } else if (getIndex(Lower_Case_Array, charArray[i]) != -1) {
                    newIndex = i + codeNum;
                    if (newIndex >= Lower_Case_Array.length) {
                        newIndex = newIndex - Lower_Case_Array.length ;
                    }
                    charArray[i] = Lower_Case_Array[newIndex];
                } else if (getIndex(digArray, charArray[i]) != -1) {
                    newIndex = i + codeNum;
                    if (newIndex >= digArray.length) {
                        newIndex = newIndex - digArray.length ;
                    }
                    charArray[i] = digArray[newIndex];
                }       
            }

            return new String(charArray);
        }

        public static int getIndex(char[] source, char filter) {
            int result = -1;
            for (int i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
                if (source[i] == filter) {
                    result = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```